# Makefile: couple syntax questions

Tags: syntax, makefile

- **package_version := $(version)x0d$(date)**

  what is the x0d part between version and date vars? is it just string?
- What **$(dotin_files:.in=)** does below

code

```
dotin_files       := $(shell find . -type f -name \*.in)
dotin_files       := $(dotin_files:.in=)
```

- what this means **$(dotin_files:=.in)**

code

```
$(dotin_files): $(dotin_files:=.in)
 $(substitute) $@.in > $@
```

- can target contain multiple files?
- what is the meaning of declaring target variable as PHONY?

code

```
.PHONY: $(dotin_files)
```

- In the regex replacement code below

code

```
substitute := perl -p -e 's/@([^@]+)@/defined $$ENV{$$1} ? $$ENV{$$1} : $$&/ge'
```

what are `$$ENV{$$1}` and `$$&`? I guess it's Perl scope...

thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Variable Expansion**

`$()` is variable expansion in make, this should just be string substitution - if your makefile is

```
version=1
date=1.1.10
package_version:=$(version)x0d$(date)
```

then the variable `package_version` will expand to `1x0d1.1.10`.

**Substitution**

The syntax `$(var:a=b)` is a [substitution reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Text-Functions.html) and will expand to `var` with a suffix `a` substituted with `b`.

For example, in

```
foobar:= foo bar
faabar:=$(foobar:oo=aa)
```

`$(faabar)` will expand to the string `faa bar`.

**Multiple Targets**

Multiple targets in a make rule is equivalent to having n rules with a single target, eg

```
foo bar:foo.c bar.c
     $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

is equivalent to

```
foo:foo.c bar.c
     $(CC) -o $@ $^
bar:foo.c bar.c
     $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

remember that any variables here are expanded.

**Phony Targets**

The `.PHONY` target declares that a rule doesn't produce an actual file, so it will always be built. As always, variables are expanded first. In your case this will expand to something like

```
.PHONY: foo bar
```

**Escaping**

A dollar sign is an escape character in makefiles, the `$$` in your perl example is a literal `$`, eg `substitute` will be the string

```
perl -p -e 's/@([^@]+)@/defined $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $&/ge'
```

The dollar signs here are processed by perl, and probably give environment variables (I don't know perl).

Comment: @Scott Wales: thanks but not quite answering my questions. I know what is variable, PHONY and escaping...

Comment: @Michael: So then which part didn't it answer?

Comment: @Scott Wales: so in accordance to my example dotin_files := $(dotin_files:.in=) will remove all .in extensions from each file name?

Answer (score 1):

Michael, you've been asking a lot of basic Makefile questions, and the ones you're asking now are ones you should be able to answer for yourself by experiment.

```
can target contain multiple files?
```

Try it:

```
dotin_files := foo.in bar.in

$(dotin_files):
    @echo $@
```

Now try `make foo.in` and `make bar.in`. What happens?

```
What $(dotin_files:.in=) does
```

It's a substitution reference. Try it yourself and see what happens, like this:

```
dotin_files := foo.in bar.in
dotin_files := $(dotin_files:.in=)

all:
    @echo $(dotin_files)
```

What did it do?

```
substitute := perl -p -e 's/@([^@]+)@/defined $$ENV{$$1} ? $$ENV{$$1} : $$&/ge'
what are $$ENV{$$1} and $$&? I guess it's Perl scope...
```

Let's take a look:

```
all:
    @echo $(substitute)
```

If you want to know more about Perl, or regexs, or find, or make, or whatever, feel free to ask here, but please take a little time to try to figure it out first.

Answer (score 1):

- x0d part between version and date vars, is it just string?
  Yes.
- What $(dotin_files:.in=) does below
  Removes the .in from the filenames found with the shell find.
- what this means $(dotin_files:=.in)
  I think you meant $(dotin_files:.in=). As already answered, within the variable dotin_files it replaces any occurrence of ".in" with an empty string(the part between the "=" and ")".
- can target contain multiple files?
  Yes
- what is the meaning of declaring target variable as PHONY?
  make will ignore targets time-stamp and consider them as new
  thus rebuilding them each time.
- In the regex replacement code below what are $$ENV{$$1} and $$&?

To avoid expansion of $ENV, the $ is doubled, think of '%' in C format strings, thus the string
perl -p -e 's/@([^@]+)@/defined $$ENV{$$1} ? $$ENV{$$1} : $$&/ge'
when called as a shell command will become:
perl -p -e 's/@([^@]+)@/defined $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : $&/ge'

$ENV is the perl Environment hash, $1 I think it's a backreference in the s/// regexp group.